# particular country user should access country/region specific website but database should be in sync across regions

Tags: azure

I want my website is available in different azure regions  and region specific user should access there region specific server hosting the website only (to minimize latency).  Also the database want to keep it more than one region under synchronization with minimum delay, all this on azure. Also can we sync database on private datacenter to be in sync with azure databases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no effort shown here.

Comment: You can have a look at cosmos Db, it should match most of your requirements but it is not  a relational database. Otherwise Sql Database supports geo replication so you can read the documentation and see which product is best for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to think about Cosmos DB for geo replication syncup of data and manage the country wise permission at application level.